# Best way read/sort data on Excel, when column 1 is subject and column 2 is the data, in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out the best way to read data and put it into either a list of the format `List[subject][data for that subject]` a data frame or an array. I have provided an image of what the data should look like approximately on Excel. I am not a csd major but I find programming rather useful in my research. So far I have managed to import the data by using openpyxl into a list and then into an array, but it seems rather messy doing it this way.

Below is my code for reading from the Excel file:

```
def read_cell (x_cord,y_cord,listofdata):

list1 = [] #my a, b c cells
currentcell_old = 0
list2 = [] #my values to be added to the cell
last_in_range = sheet.max_row + 1 #sheetmaxrow gives the ultimate row height
list3 = [] #cell's name, object

cellwrite = 0.0 #where our response is written at
cellwrite_value = 0 #the values

x=0 
newcell = 0.0
currentcell = 0.0
ro[enter image description here][1]w=2
nextcell = 0.0
cellwrite = 0 #for iteration on count

for i in range(1,last_in_range-1) :
    print(last_in_range)
    print(i)
    nextcell = (sheet.cell(row=i + x_cord, column=y_cord+1).value) #value volumetric next to (2,3)

    currentcell = (sheet.cell(row=i+ x_cord, column=y_cord).value) #cell we are on (2,3)
    newcell = (sheet.cell(row=i+ x_cord +1, column=y_cord).value) #name of the new cell to be examined (3,3)

    if i==1 : #if its step one then do this
        currentcell_old = currentcell
        list2.append(nextcell)
        list3.append(currentcell)

    if i>=(last_in_range-3): #for last 3
        list2.sort()
        list2.append(nextcell)

    elif currentcell != currentcell_old : #if its changing to a new name do this, add the new name!
        list2.sort()
        list1.append(list2)
        list3.append(currentcell)

        currentcell_old = currentcell
        list2 = [] #delete a list, could also do del list2[:] but would affect other connected values
        list2.append(nextcell)

    elif currentcell == currentcell_old : #if its the same as the old name do this
        if currentcell == 'none':
            x=1
        else:
            list2.append(nextcell)


return (list1 , list3)
```

Any comment is welcome!

[Link to my excel file simplified](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lWdPMTszipqrZv1V5QCctnFg6ESz5_F5)

Comment: the picture of my excel file did not attach for some reason, essentially is this:
row1:row2
subject1:3
subject1:2
subject1:5
subject1:1
subjectb:3
subjectb:1
subjectb:8
subjectb:2

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input data? [MCVE]

Comment: I couldnt upload an image due to small rep but i just uploaded a sample of the file..!

Comment: To clarify, column c is the object that which I want all the values on column D to be added on..

Comment: Do not post the link to your data. Simply copy paste your input data and then your expected output. I know that input data may range from 100 rows to millions hence, you need to provide a minified  example of your data. Go through the link I posted before to understand what I am asking for.

Comment: Right! I reuploaded a way simplified sample, should be ok now?

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. I only see two columns. One with image names and another with some values. I do not know what columns c and D are. Again, do not provide a link, simpy copy/paste your data so that anyone can copy that data to their terminal and reproduce the problem.

Comment: obj a 0,02473
obj a 0,00824
objb 0,00412
objb 0,01649
objb 0,01236
objc 0,02061
objc 0,00412

Comment: Look, I cant explain properly, dont waste your time if we cant come to a solution, ill try to repost later more clearly, I really do appreciate the effort....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas gives you the option to read several type of files including excel and csv. If your excel file has just one sheet then just use

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

you can specify the delimeter through sep = '' if this is not a comma.

if you want to specify the sheet you can do this through the sheet_name argument on giving its name or number.

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'sheet_name')
```

you can convert that to a list if needed through

```
df.to_list()
```

or just get the values through

```
df.values
```

and several other options through pandas

Edit: Based on your comment below you should need something like that

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, usecols=[2,3], names = ['label', 'data']) # read columns 3 and 4 from excel and give column names         

uniques = df.label.unique() # create a list with unique sbject names
for i in range(len(uniques)):
    df[uniques[i]] = df.data[df.label==uniques[i]].reset_index(drop=True) # add a new column for every with data for every unique subject
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! so the best way you think would be directly through pandas? I attached a picture but it did not seem to have been posted. My main issue is categorizing the list or dataframe by each subject when on collumn 1 i have the names of the subject for each measurement and on collumn 2 i have the measurments. I know this is a little confusing, ill try and see if I can read that into a dataframe byt doing some more researching, if not ill rephrase my question clearer and repost.

Comment: Once you read the excel file through pandas you can easily filter and group your data.  Another option could be to form a dictionary. It would be useful to provide a data sample.

Comment: I just uploaded a sample file..!

Comment: To clarify, column c is the object that which I want all the values on column D to be added on..

Comment: so if i understand correct you want a list of all data (column D) with the same label (column c). is that the case?

Comment: yes, label obj1, for example, contains all data next to it supplied on column D

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.